# Geom_text not aligned at the top of the bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

The geom_text labels are not centered at the top of the bars in the graph below, especially the last two labels (left to right):

[image]
Does anyone have any ideas to align them at the top of the bars?

I have tried some code changes, but the best one I got was:

```
my_df = data.frame(c('2017','2018','2019','2019','2019','2019','2020','2020'),
                   c(96, 91, 20.59, 47.37, 78.12, 10.00, 15.00 ,91),
                   c("No","No", "20%", "20%", "5%", "20%", "20%", "No"))        
colnames(my_df) <- c("Year","Threshold","Fee")

colors <- c("No"="seagreen3","5%"="yellow2","20%"="red4")

ggplot(data=my_df,
       aes(x=Year, y=Threshold, label=Threshold, group=Fee)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = Fee),
           position = position_dodge2(width = 1, preserve = "single")) + 
  geom_text(position = position_dodge2(width = 1), vjust=-0.5,size=2) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = cores2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution by reordering the data frame and adjusting the position_dodge2 elements.

```
my_df<-my_df[order(my_df$Year, my_df$Fee), ]
ggplot(data=my_df,aes(x=Year, y=Threshold, label=Threshold)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Fee), width=1, position = position_dodge2(width = 1, preserve = "single")) +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge2(width = 1, preserve = "single"), vjust=-0.5, size=3)
```

[image]

Comment: You are right, Dave2e. I forgot to set the parameter preserve within the geom_text layer and after changing it, the alignment problem was solved. Thank you.